# Can Public Google Sheets be accessed via ID without OAuth 2.0? If so, what credentials class do you use?

Tags: c#, oauth

Google Sheets API (also Drive API)

Basically I'm using OAuth 2.0 to gain access to a users Google Sheet List. However, if I wanted to just access public Sheets via Sheet ID, can I skip the `OAuth 2.0` process and just access them like a browser that is not logged into a gmail account? If you can, what credentials do you use?

I use `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` and it seems to require a user and go through the whole sheet access via the browser.

I'm writing this in C#.

Thanks in Advance.

I've tried:

```
m_GoogleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly);
```

Also, I tried creating a `SheetService` with no credentials.